# traer descripcion de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, tengo dos tablas , una llamada CatCodigos donde vienen unos códigos con una descripción, y otra tabla llama Desperdicio en la cual tengo un campo que trae el codigo del CatDesperdicio.

Necesito mostrar también la descripción del código, ya la incluyo en mi query pero no es la descripción del código, necesito hacer el match entre el código y la descripción

Se los agradezco mucho, estas tablas son de un sistema muy antiguo por lo que estoy desentrañando todo
Estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ajunto tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Query

```
 SELECT Desperdicio.des_Fecha AS Fecha, Desperdicio.des_Turno AS Turno, Desperdicio.des_Ord AS Orden, Desperdicio.des_Cod , CatCodigos.cod_Desc, Desperdicio.des_Cant
FROM Desperdicio, CatCodigos
WHERE des_CT = '113' AND des_Fecha BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-30'
```

Reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega la estructura de las tablas por favor

Comment: Que campo tienen en común CatCodigos y CatDesperdicio?

Comment: Probablemente con un `INNER JOIN` entre las 2 tablas por las columnas que se tienen en común, la llave primaria t foránea pudiera ser opción, apartir de ello hacer un `SELECT` de las columnas de ambas tablas que deseas obtener

Comment: Edgar Vazquez, creo que ninguno, esta BD la hicieron en el 2003, solo tengo un .bak que estoy tratando de entender

Comment: Es que si no se tiene algun campo en comun, como relacionarias la descripción de cada uno?

Comment: No tengo idea, ya subi el reporte que genera el programa, me trae la descripcion del codigo pero no tiene llave foranea ni principal

Comment: Cot_codigo de CatCodigos no sera lo mismo que des_cod de desperdicios?

Comment: Y esas descripciones que trae el programa son correctas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Desperdicio.des_Fecha AS Fecha, 
Desperdicio.des_Turno AS Turno, 
Desperdicio.des_Ord AS Orden,
Desperdicio.des_Cod , 
CatCodigos.cod_Desc, 
Desperdicio.des_Cant
FROM Desperdicio, CatCodigos
WHERE des_CT = '113' AND des_Fecha BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-30'
```

Por tu query entiendo que
des_Cod de la tabla Desperdicio y cod_Codigo de catCodigos son tu campo que funciona como referencia has la consulta con un join asi:

```
SELECT Desperdicio.des_Fecha AS Fecha, 
Desperdicio.des_Turno AS Turno, 
Desperdicio.des_Ord AS Orden,
Desperdicio.des_Cod , 
CatCodigos.cod_Desc, 
Desperdicio.des_Cant
FROM Desperdicio
join  CatCodigos on Desperdicio.des_Cod = CatCodigos.cod_Codigo
WHERE des_CT = '113' AND des_Fecha BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-30'
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, si eso fue, creo que la persona hizo dos campos con la misma informacion para relacionarlos pero no utilizo llaves foraneas ni primarias.

Comment: Me alegra haber ayudado, en cualquier caso si tienes los privilegios y la oportunidad de mejorar la base, tal vez te convenga normalizarla, ya que no veo tampoco id's como lo mencionas, te llevara tiempo pero a la larga podrías llegar a ver mejoras en tus consultas multi-tabla.